# Merging two backgrounds into one

Tags: css, reactjs, image, background, figma

Below is an image of a figma design which i working on transforming into a ReactJS page, the background consist of a gradient as follows

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #E5EFFF 0%, rgba(229, 239, 255, 0.262661) 83.7%, rgba(229, 239, 255, 0) 100%);
```

but as you see in the background there is a another white large line in right side of the page (an image) , so how i can merge the image alone with the background together ?  appreciate the feedback

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply multiple backgrounds to elements, something like this.

```css
.bg1 {
width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png),
      linear-gradient(180deg, #E5EFFF 0%, rgba(229, 239, 255, 0.262661) 83.7%, rgba(229, 239, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat,
      no-repeat;
  background-position: top right,
      right;

}
```

```html
<div class="bg1"></div>
```